# Are there "Aces" in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, warfare

On Earth, when a pilot shoots down 5 or more enemy aircraft, that pilot is called an "Ace". Is the title "Ace" awarded to pilots in Star Wars?

Comment: IIRC, Corran and another pilot in X-Wing series were given ace titles too

Comment: Yes, for example there is Ace Azzameen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep.  [Details on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ace) but here's the relevant info:

> The title of ace or space ace was conferred onto any starfighter or combat airspeeder pilot who had achieved five or more kills against enemy forces in combat. The origins of the title were unknown, but the status held equal import regardless of the era in which it was earned. Many pilots throughout the history of the galaxy earned the title of ace, with many of them exceeding the minimum number of victories by considerable margins. Among the Galactic Republic and later the Galactic Empire, particularly exceptional aces could be given the title of "Tan," which would be used before their full name.

Comment: Gives whole new meaning to "I'm gonna get a *tan*." ;)

Comment: Canon sources??

Comment: Mostly the Roleplaying game sourcebooks; [Galaxy Guide 3](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_Guide_3:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back)

Comment: @DVK the whole x-wing series, among others

Comment: @KeithHWeston - would you mind adding the exact references to the answer? It would greatly improve it (I don't doubt that they exist, that wasn't the point of my comment, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can think of at least one instance where the title of "Ace" is given to pilots. The book is "Death Star" by Michael Reaves and Steve Perry.

A TIE Fighter pilot discusses with his girlfriend his conflicting feelings about becoming a "Double Ace" in one day.

Sorry i can't recall the exact quote.

Answer (score 2):

In the short (canon) story "[Grounded](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grounded)" Senior Flight Engineer Nera Kase repeatedly refers to pilots by their squadron designation and their number of kills. More than 5 and they're an "ace", more than 10 and they're a "double ace" and so forth.

> *Red Squadron was engaging the surface batteries, now, trying to clear
>   the way for Gold One’s element. Red Three (Biggs Darklighter, 5,874
>   flight hours, **triple ace, sixteen confirmed kills**) called his target,
>   Red Six (Jek “Tono” Porkins, 10,499 flight hours, **double ace, fourteen
>   confirmed kills**) following him in and—*

And in [Before the Awakening](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Before_the_Awakening), we learn that Poe's mother was a triple-ace.

> *It wasn’t until years later, long after she had passed away and Poe
>   had entered the New Republic’s service and become a pilot himself,
>   that he began to learn the true scope of her heroism—that Lieutenant
>   Shara Bey had been awarded the Bronze Nova for Conspicuous Gallantry
>   during the Liberation of Gorma; that **she had earned her triple ace
>   less than a week later, during Operation: Mynock Bite***